# Limit array values and force type to string

Tags: typescript

I have this code:

```js
const data = {
  id: 2,
  about: "test data",
  created: new Date(), 
}

function encodeCursor<T, K extends keyof T>(node: T, fields: K[]): string | undefined {
  if (!node) {
    return;
  }

  const json = JSON.stringify(node, fields);

  return Buffer.from(json, "utf-8").toString("base64");
}

encodeCursor(data, ["id", "created"]);
```

But I get this errror:

```
error TS2769: No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 2, '(value: any, replacer?: ((this: any, key: string, value: any) => any) | undefined, space?: string | number | undefined): string', gave the following error.
    Argument of type 'K[]' is not assignable to parameter of type '(this: any, key: string, value: any) => any'.
      Type 'K[]' provides no match for the signature '(this: any, key: string, value: any): any'.
  Overload 2 of 2, '(value: any, replacer?: (string | number)[] | null | undefined, space?: string | number | undefined): string', gave the following error.
    Argument of type 'K[]' is not assignable to parameter of type '(string | number)[]'.
      Type 'K' is not assignable to type 'string | number'.
        Type 'keyof T' is not assignable to type 'string | number'.
          Type 'string | number | symbol' is not assignable to type 'string | number'.
            Type 'symbol' is not assignable to type 'string | number'.
              Type 'keyof T' is not assignable to type 'number'.
                Type 'K' is not assignable to type 'number'.
                  Type 'keyof T' is not assignable to type 'number'.
                    Type 'string | number | symbol' is not assignable to type 'number'.
                      Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'number'.
```

I want `fields` to be limited to keys of `data` and with type `string`, I understand that the current Typescript error is because the type of each value of `fields` isn't `string`.

Comment: What are you expecting to be able to pass as the second argument of `JSON.stringify`? If ought to be a function, [see the docs to find out more.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify)

Comment: See the documentation to the second argument: `replacer:
A function that alters the behavior of the stringification process, or an array of String and Number that serve as a whitelist for selecting/filtering the properties of the value object to be included in the JSON string. If this value is null or not provided, all properties of the object are included in the resulting JSON string.` so an array is valid.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow - **`replacer: A function`**; it's a function?

Comment: Continue reading - **replacer: ... or an array ...**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is right here:

> Type 'string | number | symbol' is not assignable to type 'string | number'.

`keyof T` includes [`symbol`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol) types. Since you just want string-valued keys, you can only accept values that are keys of `T` and type `string` using an intersection type:

```js
function encodeCursor<T>(node: T, fields: Array<keyof T & string>): string | undefined {
  if (!node) {
    return;
  }

  const json = JSON.stringify(node, fields);

  return Buffer.from(json, "utf-8").toString("base64");
}
```